# max-width: 100% not working

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to do a chat-like thing, which has the following structure:

```
<div class="chat">
    <div id="messagesWrap" class="chat-messages">
        <table id="chat">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    A certain long text, whos length overflows the "chat" container div.
                </td>
            </tr>
            //some more <tr><td> pairs go here with JS.
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I have the following CSS:

```
.chat
{
    position: absolute;

    min-width: 400px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.chat-messages
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#chat
{
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#chat>tbody
{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The problem with this all, is that the max-width property doesn't work on neither table, nor tbody. The contents of td make the whole structure up to table expend its width beyond the maxwidth, which should be 100% of width of the topmost div. No matter what I do, or what I try to search in google, I can't find the solution to this. Perhaps there's something with higher priority than max-width?

Also, I am using chrome.

Comment: I guess you will want to check out using `!important` before `;`.

Comment: Am I missing something or does it actually work? http://jsfiddle.net/b4bCx/

Comment: Oh, further experiments shown that it actually works, but 100% isn't the parent elements width in my case for some reason. Parent width is 400px, and the max width becomes 1154px...

Comment: And even further experements shown that it's actually NOT working, and the 1154px width limit comes out of nowhere.

Comment: Why not using floating divs instead of table-design...

Answer (score 2):

The `max-width` property prevents the element from exceeding the width of its parent, so you can set a certain width to the table container `class chat-messages` and use `max-width: 100%;` in your table. Using `max-width: 100%;` in both means that they can both fill the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "max-width: 100%;" means the width can't be more than the whole container that the component is in.  The width can be very anything and take up the whole container (div or table).  This won't stop the size of the component you're adding changing the container's size.

To fix this you'll have set the max-width to an actual value (like you did with min-width) instead of just making it take up the whole container (which can still be any size).

Hope this helps...

Edit:  As you've said in previous comments, try max the max-width apply to the td element instead of the whole table element.

Comment: Or even better, apply different width for each td (to make the table better formatted and more readable)

Comment: Yes, it would work if I used fixed sizes in px, but the whole poin of this questin is to get it working with percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Your main div `.chat` has this properties

```
.chat
{
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 400px;
  **width: 20%;**
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

You set the main parent with `width:20%` and that's way your table content is showing small and not applying to `max-width:100%` of `.chat-messages` class.